# Magento 2 workflow exporting and importing between Local > Staging and Production configuration and database

Tags: magento2, database, configuration

I have a local Magento 2 installation and the code is controlled by Git. The dependencies are installed by Composer. I have a copy of this site moved to the Staging server and Production server.

But what is advisible/are best practices to handle the configuration and the databases?

- In which environment I am doing configurations?
- In which environment I am adding products and create cms pages etc?
- On the production site there is also new customer and order
  information in the database.

How do I sync or handle this best and most simplest way? Or do I have to do configuration on all environments separately in Magento admin (because it's only a one-time thing?

Comment: Why is it only a one time thing?  If you're looking for best practice yes it needs to go from either dev server (or local) to staging for review and QA to production.  For each feature / upgrade you should do this?  I fail to see how it is only 1 time.

Comment: I mean with 'one-time thing' the configuration of tax settings, shipping, payments etc. Af course products, orders and customers is a continuous process. But for example: now I (or my client) have to add all the products. Can we do this on staging? Because the staging server everybody can view and reach...

Comment: For your situation if you work in a group I would say yes this is easiest.  Staging means that they need to be examples of real products.  I would at least copy the database over to the local / development server.  Production... not sure if i would copy the DB (database) and rsync the media folder.  Some of these could have been for testing transactions.

Comment: @camdixon And to export the products from staging > dev (and to production) or vice versa can I also use Magento product export feature? What is the difference exporting the DB vs Magento product export feature?